# Button disable after one click and clear text input // Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a anroid app which is giving a random word from a array. so i have a button which is disabled if there is no input in the text field. after the user added some text the button is enabled and give some random word from my array. all is working good BUT the problem is: after the user makes his first input in the text field he can click the button as many times as he want. i want that the button is just clickable for one time after the user puts text into the textfield. so one output from the array for one text input into the textfield. So --> input text --> button enable and just one output from the array --> button disable and clear the input field and waiting for new user input text again --> button enable and just one output from the array --> button disable ... and so on...

here is my code which i have so far for the text and button

```
inputtext=findViewById(R.id.frage)
        action_button=findViewById(R.id.button)


        inputtext.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher

        {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }


            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

                action_button.isEnabled=true


            }


        })
```

thanks for your help and im using Android Studio with Kotlin. regards

Comment: How about `action_button.setOnClickListener { action_button.isEnabled = false ... }`?

Comment: the true is right, because the button should be enabled after a user makes text input. but i want to disable the button after the button click and text output. than clearing the textfield, disable the button and waiting for new text input to enable the button again. regards